# Waiting on a child process in perl

Tags: perl, unix, posix, fork, ipc

I am having an issue with capturing the return status of the child process. below is a simplified version of my code.

```
use Modern::Perl;
use POSIX;
use AnyEvent;

my @jobs = (1, 7, 3, 9 , 4 , 2);
my %pid;
my %running;

my $t = AE::timer 0, 5, sub{
    while(scalar( keys %running < 3) && scalar (@jobs)){
        my $job = shift @jobs;
        $running{$job}=1;
        $pid{$job} = run($job);
    }
    for(keys %running){
        delete $running{$_} unless check($pid{$_},$_);
    }
    exit unless scalar keys %running;
};

AnyEvent->condvar->recv;

sub func_to_run{
    my $id = shift;
    close STDOUT;
    open STDOUT, ">>$id.log";
    exec '/bin/sleep', $id;
}

sub run{
    my $id = shift;
    print "starting job $id\n";
    my $pid = fork();
    return $pid if $pid;
    func_to_run($id);
}

sub check{
    my ($pid,$id) = @_;
    my $result = waitpid($pid, WNOHANG);
    {
        if ($result == $pid) {
            my $rc = $? >> 8;
            print "Job $id finished with code $rc\n";
            return 0;
        }
        elsif ($result == -1 and $! == ECHILD) {
            print "Job $id finished running, not sure if it was sucessfull\n";
            return 0;
        }
        elsif ($result == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        redo;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
starting job 1
starting job 7
starting job 3
Job 1 finished running, not sure if it was sucessfull
Job 3 finished running, not sure if it was sucessfull
starting job 9
starting job 4
Job 7 finished running, not sure if it was sucessfull
starting job 2
Job 4 finished running, not sure if it was sucessfull
Job 9 finished running, not sure if it was sucessfull
Job 2 finished running, not sure if it was sucessfull
```

why is waitpid() returning -1 instead of a return status?

EDIT:
I changed system + exit to exec. This was what I was originally doing. My goal is to be able to signal the child process, which I don't actually think can be done with system.

```
kill($pid,'HUP');
```

EDIT 2:
    There can be several child processes running at once, and this is being called from a AE::timer module. what I want to figure out here is why I am getting -1 from waitpid() which indicates that the child was reaped.

EDIT 3: I have changed the code to a full working example with the output I get

Comment: Do you have `$SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';` set somewhere?

Comment: No, I didn't set that signal handler. I have edited the question to be slightly more clear

Comment: Wait, what?  You want the child process to signal itself?  `kill HUP => $$`  But ... why?

Comment: no, I want the parent process to be able to signal the child process.

Comment: Why do you use `WNOHANG`? Note that your code doesn't even declare that symbol (or `ECHILD`)! Always use `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Wait, are you saying (in update 2) that it's different code than the code you posted that results in the behaviour you described? Please post code that actually exhibits the behaviour you describe. -1, posted code does not exhibit the stated behaviour.

Comment: While the code is more complex, essentially the above is whats going wrong. I didn't add the perl modules being used, but it uses the POSIX module as well as Modern::Perl(which includes both strict and warnings)

Comment: Please, can you extend your sample code to be complete? If I try your code above and add the missing parts (use of POSIX, Errno, strict, print out the $code), then I *cannot* reproduce the problem (unless `$SIG{CHLD}` is set).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked what your code is actually doing with the `strace` command on linux. The following is what you see as one of the `sleep` commands completes:

```
$ strace -f perl test.pl
...
[pid  4891] nanosleep({1, 0}, NULL)     = 0
[pid  4891] close(1)                    = 0
[pid  4891] close(2)                    = 0
[pid  4891] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid  4891] +++ exited with 0 +++
 2061530, 64, 4990) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4891, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
write(4, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
rt_sigreturn()                          = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {97657, 317300660}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {97657, 317371410}) = 0
epoll_wait(3, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=4, u64=4294967300}}}, 64, 3987) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {97657, 317493076}) = 0
read(4, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)          = 8
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = 4891
wait4(-1, 0x7fff8f7bc42c, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {97657, 317738921}) = 0
epoll_wait(3, {}, 64, 3986)             = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {97661, 304667812}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {97661, 304719985}) = 0
epoll_wait(3, {}, 64, 1)                = 0
...
```

The lines starting `[pid  4891]` are from the `sleep` command, and the rest are from your script. You can see that the script is invoking the `wait4()` system call and returning the PID of the sleep process — presumably as part of the event loop that the script is using. This is why you’re getting -1 from your call to `waitpid()` — the child process has already been reaped.

By the way, the AnyEvent documentation has a section ([CHILD PROCESS WATCHERS](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/AnyEvent-7.05/lib/AnyEvent.pm#CHILD_PROCESS_WATCHERS)) on watching child processes and examining their return codes. From the documentation:

```
my $done = AnyEvent->condvar;

my $pid = fork or exit 5;

my $w = AnyEvent->child (
   pid => $pid,
   cb  => sub {
      my ($pid, $status) = @_;
       warn "pid $pid exited with status $status";
      $done->send;
   },
);

# do something else, then wait for process exit
$done->recv;
```

With regard to using `system()` or `exec()` to spawn the process, you are correct to use `exec()`. This is because `system()` creates a sub-process to execute its command in whereas `exec()` replaces the current process with the command. This means that the `$pid` from the `system()` would refer to the forked Perl script, and not to the command run by the Perl script.